# validators = [MinValueValidator] does not work in Django

Tags: python, django

I want to set the minimum value for FloatField in Django so that the form field does not accept negative value. In case of Integers I changed the datatype to PositiveIntegerField but minimum value is not working in case of float field.

```
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator

max_discount = models.FloatField( verbose_name=u'Maximum Discount', validators = [MinValueValidator(0.0)])
```

Comment: Your `max_discount` field looks ok. What do you mean by 'does not work'? What are you trying to do, what do you expect to happen, and what happens?

Comment: I just realized that the validators work when the form is submitted but I wanted that the field does not allow the negative value to be entered just like PositiveIntegerField does.

Answer (score 29):

Your code:

```
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator

max_discount = models.FloatField( verbose_name=u'Maximum Discount', validators = [MinValueValidator(0.0)])
```

looks fine. 
You should note though that

> validators will not be run automatically when you save a model, but if
>   you are using a ModelForm, it will run your validators on any fields
>   that are included in your form.

See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/validators/#how-validators-are-run) for more info.

You can add some sort of html attribute validation in your form too, for example:

```
<input type="number" min="0.0">
```

to your server-side validation.

**EDIT**

If your form field is in the admin interface you can customize the widget (basically the HTML) for this field. You can see [here](http://garmoncheg.blogspot.ro/2014/07/django-adding-custom-widget-to-django.html) how to add a custom widget to a field in the admin interface.

Comment: oOoo... Is it that the validation message will appear if the form is submitted? 
But I wanted that the field does not allow negative value to be entered just like the PositiveIntegerField does.

Comment: there is no template I am working on django admin interface.

Answer (score 1):

I have done the same thing like this,

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, MaxValueValidator

class Coupon(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=50,
                               unique=True)
    valid_from = models.DateTimeField()
    valid_to = models.DateTimeField()
    discount = models.IntegerField(
                      validators=[MinValueValidator(0),
                                  MaxValueValidator(100)])
    active = models.BooleanField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.code
```

I have set discount code like this,

```
discount = models.IntegerField(
                          validators=[MinValueValidator(0),
                                      MaxValueValidator(100)])
```

discount: The discount rate to apply (this is a percentage, so it takes values from 0 to 100). We use validators for this field to limit the minimum and maximum accepted values.

You can try this way might be working for you.

Thanks.

Comment: validators neither work with integerfield nor with floatfield. I dont know whats the issue.

Comment: @ManpreetAhluwalia, Are you running you're a project with "virtualenv"? If not then secure your project directory by using this. sometimes this causes the issue. I have experienced many times. It might solve your issue automatically. Thanks.

Comment: I just realized that the validators work when the form is submitted but I wanted that the field does not allow the negative value to be entered just like PositiveIntegerField does.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is in the definition of the decimal.
You should do it like this:

```
validators = [MinValueValidator(Decimal('0.0'))]
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, your answer looks correct, but if you add the explanation as why that format is necessary it would add to the clarity and completeness.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own PositiveFloatField that extends FloatField and customize it as you like

```
class PositiveFloatField(FloatField):
description = _("Positive Float")

@cached_property
def validators(self):
    validators_ = super().validators

    validators_.append(validators.MinValueValidator(0.0))
    return validators_

def formfield(self, **kwargs):
    return super().formfield(**{
        'min_value': 0.0,
        **kwargs,
    })
```

Then in your model:

```
height = PositiveFloatField(verbose_name=_("Height"), null=True, blank=True)
```